# Can other latex citation commands like citep and citet be used in notebook markdown cells?

Tags: latex, ipython, jupyter-notebook

So nbconvert knows how to deal with lines in markdown cells like like

`<cite data-cite="granger2013">(Granger, 2013)</cite>`

which ends up looking like `\cite{...}` in the .tex files.

Is there a way of also using `\citep` , `\citet` etc in markdown cells?

Ta.

Comment: Not by default. You could modify the citation filter to do what you want: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/nbconvert/filters/citation.py

Comment: So seems the options there would be to have a special flag in the text string and then do some text replacement the .tex file, , or to have a different parsing stream for e.g. 'citet' vs. 'cite' citations. I can certainly see some dirty ways how this could be done. Something I'm not sure about is the 'data-cite' attribute? Would it be possible to add in an arbitrary number of additional ones for 'date-cite' citations than  or to have additional attributes like 'data-citet', 'data-citep', etc.?

Comment: If I understand you, either should be possible.

Comment: (FYI to readers this discussion has moved to ipython dev list and ipython github repo)